# executing powershell with php

Tags: php, powershell, wmi, powershell-remoting

I have following script to get the status of service of remote computer and display it on web page (I have powershell v3.0 installed):

```
<html !DOCTYPE>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<?php 
    $output = exec('powershell.exe "(Get-Service -computername server_name wudfsvc).Status"');
    echo $output  
?>

</body>
</html>
```

This works, when I check status of service locally (without -computername parameter) and it works when I run this script in command line. I think, that the problem is, that when I run it in php, it has insufficient rights to get the status of service on the remote computer. I've tried to use "Get-WMIObject -class win32_service" instead of Get-Service, but I only found this example which provides only login without password:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -Credential FABRIKAM\administrator Computer Fabrikam
```

I need to get status of service on remote computer automatically without user interaction. Is it possible?

Thank you!

Comment: What user account is PHP being run on?

Comment: Thank you for response, vonPryz. I'm logged in with my domain account. How do I check the account PHP is running on?

Comment: It's running under whatever account your web server is running under. But allowing your web server process to have this level of access to the rest of your network is a security concern that you must consider *very* carefully.

Comment: alroc, I considered it carefully. I need to monitor my systems and this is the simplest way I found. If there is some other way (with higher security) to accomplish this, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

PHP interacts using the local IIS service account.  I usually assign rights to the local IUSR group.